# IPTABLES Block FXP download from a IP

Tags: downloads, iptables, upload

I am trying to block an FXP upload from a specific IP eg. 188.145.11.10.

The problem is that I want to allow a download to 188.145.11.10 but I want to BLOCK the upload from that IP.

For example:

188.145.11.11 sends to 188.145.11.10 ACCEPT

188.145.11.10 sends to 188.145.11.11 DENY

Any ideas?

Comment: If you do an overall iptables rule set properly what you want to do will be O.K. Why? Because your outgoing initiation will create a "RELATED, ESTABLISHED" return path. However your incoming initiation would be "NEW", and if the rules say so, be blocked. If you provide your current complete iptables rule set, we could suggest the appropriate modifications. ( myself, I prefer the output from `sudo iptables -v -x -n -L` )

Answer (score 0):

first of all thanks for helping me. Here is my output:

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 679 packets, 267908 bytes)
pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       188.145.11.10        0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
0        0 DROP       all  --  *      *       188.145.11.10        0.0.0.0/0

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 693 packets, 300032 bytes)
pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       188.145.11.10        0.0.0.0/0            state NEW,ESTABLISHED

And thats my commands:

$IPTABLES -A INPUT -s 188.145.11.10 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -A OUTPUT -s 188.145.11.10 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,NEW -j ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -s 188.145.11.10 -j DROP

This commands result in:

188.145.11.11 sends to 188.145.11.10 DENY

188.145.11.10 sends to 188.145.11.11 ALLOW

but i need it contrariwise.